# .htaccess permanent redirect to www

Tags: wordpress, htaccess, redirects

I have a WordPress installation that is not redirecting URLs not starting with `www`.

Example: `http://example.com/dir/` doesn't send to `http://www.example.com/dir/` instead goes to `http://example.com/`.

How do I change the *.htaccess* below to always redirect to the page either using `www` or not?

```
# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# uploaded files
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$2 [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule  ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule  ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This snippet will force the `www` to always be in thew URL. I don't know if that helps you or not:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: +1 ... and this snippet should work in all cases *if* you put it *before* the `RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]` directive.

Comment: danlefree, thanks for that note. That small tip fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Altering the *.htaccess* shouldn't be necessary. You should only need to change the website URL under *Settings -> General* in the WP Admin to include the `www`.

If you try John's answer and you have the website URL in WP settings set to the `non-www` version, you will create a redirect loop.

Answer (score 0):

I would mix the two answers above

1. you HAVE to set properly the website URL So that the CMS always prints the correct address
2. you can set a proper rewrite rule  so that in case someone links the wrong URL (`no-www`) you don't end up with Google indexing all pages twice penalizing the SEO ranking