# Redirect domain.tld to www.domain.tld in Parallels Plesk Panel

Tags: redirects, shared-hosting, plesk

I inherited a website which has been set up in Parallels Plesk Panel as `www.domain.tld`. Now the problem is that `domain.tld` shows the default Parallels Plesk page and doesn't redirect to `www`. I've read in many places the solution for the opposite problem but can't find anything for this!

Is there a way to correct this? Or do I have to recreate the website?

Comment: possible duplicate of [.htaccess permanent redirect to www](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/5349/htaccess-permanent-redirect-to-www)

Comment: Please let us know your OS, web server, and version of Plesk, and what if any configuration changes you made prior to this occurring. Typically restarting the server after configuration changes will resolve this issue. You might also want to post on their [forum](http://forum.parallels.com/forumdisplay.php?208-Parallels-Plesk-Panel-for-Linux). If you find the answer, please provide it below and accept it so your question can be considered closed.

Comment: @Zistoloen - I don;t think it's the same problem. There is no domain.tld configured at all (hence no .htaccess).

Comment: @dan - It's a hosted solution, no idea of the OS. Let me try posting on their forum. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since simply renaming the domain from `www.domain.tld` to `domain.tld` didn't work at first (the error was saying that `domain.tld` already existed), I created an alias as `domain.tld`. This wasn't working either (circular redirection?), so I deleted the alias and suddenly I was able to rename the domain. Now it works fine.